# is there any way to plot these two curves in one single graph by using subplot?

Tags: python, plot

Just wondering how I could include these two plots in a single plot (images attached). I'm beginner python user. Not sure how to do it?. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def particles_speed(v,T,m):

    kb = 1.38e-23
    return (m/(2*np.pi*kb*T))**1.5*4*np.pi*v**2*np.exp(-m*v**2/(2*kb*T))
v = np.linspace(0, 2000, 3000)

amu = 1.66e-27
m = 32*amu
m = 0.910e-30

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)


for T in [1000]:
    particles = particles_speed(v,T,m)
    ax.plot(v,particles,label='T='+str(T)+' K',lw=1)

    ax.legend(loc=0)
    ax.set_xlabel('v (m/s)')
    ax.set_ylabel('#Particles f(v), PDF')
    ax.grid()
```

Plot 1
[image: image1]

Plot 2
[image: image2]

I've tried to include two "m" values but not sure how to add the other subplot.

Answer (score 0):

Believe the problem here is your for T in [1000]: line
This for each loop goes through each value in the array [1000], but there is only one value in the array. Furthermore, if you want both graphs in the same figure, you can do ax.plot() twice without any need for a for loop.